# Angular 13: Material Tabs with bodyClass not working

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-tab

I set according the [Angular Doc](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTab) the `bodyClass` in the following example:

```
 <mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">

    <mat-tab label="Documents">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
                  <app-container1></app-container1>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Documents2"  [bodyClass]="'tab-item-meta'">
              <app-ref-main1></app-ref-main1>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

and have in the corresponding *.scss file:

```
.tab-item-meta {
    height: 70vh;
}
```

When I open the Developer Console (either in FF or Chromium) I see that the class `tab-item-meta` is applied. But there the values of the `scss` file are not applied. When I try to add a code like

```
<div class="tab-item-meta">test</div>
```

then I see [image] i.e. the class is applied. It seems like this extra attribute `_ngcontent-mgf-c556` is missing for the `mat-tab-body`.

==> How to use the `bodyClass` properly?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me:

```
:host::ng-deep {
  .tab-item-meta {
     height: 70vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code ‍ snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation ‍](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future , and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the class `mat-tab-body-content` instead. I have just test it on Angular 13. You must set main container the height and in this case is the tab height and not directly to your div. `bodyClass` works as it should be but the problem is not it in this case.

```
  :host::ng-deep {
       .mat-tab-body-content {
           height: 70vh;
       }
  }
```